# Wordpress multisite issue - subsite admin no longer working

Tags: php, wordpress

We have a wordpress multisite (subdirectory set up).  It was working witout issue a few weeks ago.  (We generally do updates weekly to any necessary plugins and the core, etc.)

Both of the front ends of the sites work (what the users see).  The issue is in the admin / dashboard access.

So in our case, we have:

- network
- us (main site)
- ca

We can get to the main site admin without issue.

If we follow the link in that admin to our network dashboard, the link fails:

https://blog.konicaminolta.us/wp-admin/network/

If we update the link to include the "wordpress" directory, it works:

https://blog.konicaminolta.us/wordpress/wp-admin/network/

Our current directory setup is (and has been from day 1):

- htdocs

  - wordpress

    - wp-content, and all other wordpress files, etc.

It seems like an update (core or plugin?) may have changed a setting somewhere?

We can get into the CA site, but we run into errors like:

- admin-ajax.php not found
- The CA site displays without any CSS of any kind

We tried to do a restore from backup, that failed as well.  (Site went down with "critical error" and we had to do a manual restore from backup.)

Any thoughts?  The primary questions is how / where we can fix the setup to account for the Wordpress directory or how else we can fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by a plugin. Deactivate all plugins and see if the issue still exists.